# I am not able to edit existing LTspice directives; I always need to create new

Tags: simulation, ltspice

Once I place the directive command I will not be able to edit it -Rarely I will be-. So I always make a new directive when I need to edit the already existing ones.

I have re-installed LTspice, with no results plus it seems I cannot find any similar problem online. A colleague told me that he had a similar problem that is now fixed (somehow?). So I hope someone has encountered and solved the same problem.

Comment: You'd told us that you can't edit them, but you haven't described what the actual issue is! How are you trying? At what step does it fail? What specifically isn't working?

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer, just that the BUG came into existence in newer versions of LTspice. Post 2018.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this is the type of directive you're talking about, but the solution is to ignore LTSpice's new and fancy parametric GUI that doesn't seem to actually edit anything, at least not when I try.

When I try to edit a simple `.STEP` command I'm greeted by this dialogue that often does not work:

[image]

If I hit *Cancel* here, I'm instead greeted with the old edit window, which always works:

[image]

You can go directly to the old working edit window by holding down `Ctrl` while right-clicking on the command you want to edit.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works fine. It was really frustrating to create new commands every time

Comment: This totally saved my day! How frustrating LTSpice interface is!

Answer (score 0):

You could be not using the correct method to attempt to edit the spice directive.

With just the default cursor active *(none of the modal commands like copy, move, drag being active)* you simply right click on the spice directive and the edit box will pop-up.

Give this a try and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: No, it is not that I am using spice for the first time. I did not have this problem before. It is also strange that directives that start with a dot (.tran .param .meas) will not change, while commands that don't have a dot (i.e simulating a clock signal VcklSW2 SW_lf2 0 DC 0 pulse -1 1 200u 1n 1n 200u 0.2551) will change.